# mysql AUTO_INCREMENT skips valid range of numbers after INSERT....SELECT on table

Tags: mysql

My INSERT... SELECT query inserts 2,546 records into a table which brings my ID range for all inserted records from 176,439 to 178,984. All records are successfully inserted (178984 - 176439 + 1 = 2,546). Now if launch my application and add a single new record, my next ID appears as 180534. I don't understand mysql didn't set it to 178985. Similar behavior happens if I repeat the process.

My innodb_autoinc_lock_mode is set to 1, the default, which stands for "consecutive".

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would like to add that the rowcount for the SELECT part of the query is the same as the rowcount (rows affected) after I run INSERT...SELECT. I'm on localhost, and I'm the only user, and I am not deleting additional rows after the bulk insert.

Answer (score 1):

The number of records does not have to match the auto-increment id. Records may have been deleted. The auto-increment was set manually or for other reasons. You can set the next id with this command

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 178985;
```

After that the IDs should be generated above that number.

Comment: Hi Juergen, no records were deleted after INSERT.. SELECT - only added a record. I'm familiar with the ALTER TABLE but was more interested in why it skipped such a large range of numbers. After performing the bulk insert, I even closed my Mysql Workbench to ensure that my session ended.

Comment: Maybe there are some trigger running on that table that insert and delete records.

Comment: There's no trigger on the table that inserts and deletes records

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you ran some other insert query, rows were rejected probably due to unique constraints but auto-increment still incremented, or they were deleted after that. Alternatively if someone else (or you in another session) started a transaction, inserted some rows but didn't commit yet... the auto_increment value would also be larger.

Comment: No, this is on localhost, I'm the only users. I confirmed the SELECT count versus the INSERT...SELECT row count, and the same number of rows appear (rows affected after bulk insert). I immediately switched to my app, added a single row, then it displayed 178985. Auto_increment works fine for adding multiple rows after each other (have been for 3 years now), just not after the bulk insert.

Comment: Well, something must have happened and those are pretty much all the ways I know of that it can get altered, plus the way @juergend suggested.

Comment: Same here, which is baffling. The gap, 1550, is not in relation to anything I can think of. Other times, the gap has been different (in the hundreds, for example). It's repeatable.

Comment: Check to see if you have any IDs higher than your current auto_increment, if that's the case it's natural for the skip to occur. Maybe you accidentally corrupted some ids at some point.

Comment: I was hoping that would be the issue, but it's not. I just ran "select * from table1 where id >= 178984;" and 2 records came back - the top one in the bulk insert and the single one added via the app.

Comment: Well, sorry, I'm out of ideas, anyway, why is it so important that there are no gaps in the ids?